# Building arrays in a class and unhandled exceptions

Tags: c++, arrays

I am very new to programming and I was trying to create a phone book application involve arrays.  I want to essentially take a large number of contact's info and have the person be able to search for them.

Every time I try to compile the code, it works, and then when I press 1 to enter a contact and I enter the first name, I get this "Unhandled exception at 0x000f2ceb in assignment7.23.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x99d0627c."

I'm not sure what this means or what is wrong with my code.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class AddressBook {

public:

string myContactsFirstName[100];
string myContactsLastName[100];
string myContactsEmailAddress[100];
string myContactsPhone[100];
int index;

AddressBook() {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        myContactsFirstName[i] = "";
        myContactsLastName[i] = "";
        myContactsEmailAddress[i] = "";
        myContactsPhone[i] = "";
    }
}

void addContact() {
    cout << "Enter the first name of the contact: " << endl;
    string firstname;
    cin >> firstname;
    myContactsFirstName[index] = firstname;

    cout << "Last Name:" << endl;
    string lastname;
    cin >> lastname;
    myContactsLastName[index] = lastname;

    cout << "Phone Number: " << endl;
    string phone;
    cin >> phone;
    myContactsPhone[index] = phone;

    cout << "Email Address: " << endl;
    string address;
    cin >> address;
    myContactsEmailAddress[index] = address;

    system("pause");
    index++;
}

    void deleteLastContact(){
        myContactsFirstName[index] = "";
        myContactsLastName[index] = "";
        myContactsPhone[index] = "";
        myContactsEmailAddress[index] = "";
        index--;

        cout << "Contact deleted." << endl;


    }
};

int main() {
AddressBook myPeople;
string target;

while(1){
    cout << "Enter 1 to add a contact." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 to search contacts." << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 to delete a contact." << endl;
    cout << "Enter anything else to leave the program" << endl;

    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
        case 1: myPeople.addContact();
            break;
        case 2: {
        cout << "Enter the info to search for your contact:" << endl;
        cin >> target;

        for (int i = 0; i < myPeople.index; i++) {
            if (myPeople.myContactsFirstName[i].compare(target) == 0 )
                    cout << "We have a match" << endl;
        }
            break;
                }

        case 3: {
            myPeople.deleteLastContact();
            break;
                }
        default: exit(0);

}
}

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should include the programming language, also as a tag.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Thank you for informing me.  I will be sure to do this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Index` is uninitialized:

```
AddressBook() {
   int index = 0; //created a new index variable, fix this by deleting "int"
   ^^^
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      myContactsFirstName[i] = "";
      myContactsLastName[i] = "";
      myContactsEmailAddress[i] = "";
      myContactsPhone[i] = "";
      }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I didn't even think of that.  Thank you.  I changed it and it worked.